# how to get selenium dependency chromedriver installed up and running

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "facebookFOF.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/Users/ciasto/pyenvs/fbgraph/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/ciasto/pyenvs/fbgraph/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I went to the chrome driver url shown above and downloaded the setup for my mac os, I ran it but gets stuck at:

```
ciasto$ /Users/ciasto/Downloads/chromedriver; exit
Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not run chromedriver separately. Either set path in the script using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
```

Or as suggested, add it to your PATH.

Comment: tried but did not help

Answer (score -1):

put the [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) in the same folder as your `.py` script

and do the following :

```py
import os
from selenium import webdriver

BASE_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # get script directory 

CHROME_DRIVER_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'chromedriver') # create chrome driver path

driver =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
```

Comment: tried but did not help